# How should I format a bootable Ubuntu USB drive on macOS Sierra?

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, format, macbook-pro

I am trying to create a bootable USB drive of Ubuntu 16.04 for my Macbook Pro running the new macOS Sierra. I'm not sure which Format and Scheme I should format my new USB to so it would be able to boot on a Windows computer or a Mac.

I used to have it working (even installed it with persistence) until I upgraded from Mountain Lion to Sierra (since I accidentally formatted my entire hard drive...oops).

The USB I had it installed to got wiped before i upgraded, so now that I upgraded I am having trouble creating a new one. I used to use MS-DOS(FAT) as my Format, but now there is the additional option of Scheme with this new update.

Which is the best scheme to use while formatting; the GUID Partition Map, Master Boot Record, or the Apple Partition Map?

Comment: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos

Comment: if you don't need persistence you can just `dd` the ubuntu ISO - no formatting requires. don't `dd` your entire mac hard drive, though